# Mostrar arreglo de datos en JTextField

Tags: java, array, jframe, jtextfield

Tengo un arreglo pero tengo dificultades al saber como mostrarlo en el Frame, en el cual tengo dos botones uno de avanzar y otro de retroceder, cuando toco uno de los dos tienen que mostrarse tanto los usuarios como las contraseñas. A continuación muestro el código del un jButton:

```
  private void AvanzarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
String[ ] usuarios = new String[5];
usuarios[0] = "Eloisa";
usuarios[1] = "Amada";
usuarios[2] = "Esperanza";
usuarios[3] = "John";
usuarios[4] = "Christian";

for (int i=0;i<usuarios.length;i++){

    txtuser.setText(String.valueOf(usuarios[i]));
}

}
```

Así mismo tengo el arreglo de las contraseñas pero la dificultad para mostrarlo en el jTextField.

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.toString(usuarios)`. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo resolvi de esta forma:
Declare una variable que se llama movimientos la cual la inicialize en 0 esa variable es la que aumentara o disminuira cada vez que oprimas algun boton, debido a que solo vas a mostrar un dato cada vez que oprimas un boton al momento de que el flujo del programa entre en el for solo mostrara un dato y despues el for finalizara, para hacer esto iguale la variable i que recorre el for con la variable movimientos, para que sepa desde que posicion debe de mostrar datos.

```
   private void AdelanteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //Este es el arreglo que mostraste en tu pregunta:  
String[ ] usuarios = new String[5];
usuarios[0] = "Eloisa";
usuarios[1] = "Amada";
usuarios[2] = "Esperanza";
usuarios[3] = "John";
usuarios[4] = "Christian";
//Esta estructura esta para que en el dado caso de que llegues al final de los datos ya no se sume 1 a la variable movimientos
if(movimientos==4){
    
}else{
//Cada vez que se oprime el boton que nombre adelante, se le sumara 1 a la variable movimientos
   movimientos+=1; 
}
for (int i=movimientos;i<usuarios.length;i++){
  //Envio el texto al JTextFile
    nombres.setText(usuarios[i]);
    
   //Al hacer que i valga 4, cuando el for quiera seguir automaticamente se dara cuenta de que la condicion planteada es false y terminara
    i=4;
}
  
        
    }                                        
//Boton para retroceder:
    private void AtrasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // Mismo arreglo
         String[ ] usuarios = new String[5];
usuarios[0] = "Eloisa";
usuarios[1] = "Amada";
usuarios[2] = "Esperanza";
usuarios[3] = "John";
usuarios[4] = "Christian";
if(movimientos==0){
    //Caso contrario, al momento de oprimir el boton atras, por cualquier motivo que se de en el cual la variable movientos llegue a 0 este condicional evitara que se le reste 1 ya que pueda sucitarse una situacion en la que la variable adquiere un valor de -1 y eso no debe de ocurrir    
    }else{
//Cada vez que oprimes el boton atras se le resta 1
    movimientos-=1;
    }
//como i=movimientos, el for muestra desde donde esta el dato, en este caso la posicion anterior.
for (int i=movimientos;i<usuarios.length;i++){

    nombres.setText(usuarios[i]);
   
    i=4;
}
    }
```

Te aconsejo que declares el arreglo en otra clase.......
nota: este codigo que subi solo muestra los nombres, pero tambien puede aplicarse para mostrar el  otro campo que era contraseña, lo unico que hay que hacer es agregar el fragmento de codigo en el que se mandan datos al campo de la contraseña, la logica es la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría seria lo siguiente

Declarar una clase persona con atributos nombre y contraseña

Declaras un arreglo de tipo persona y creas cada persona con su nombre y contraseña correspondiente y lo agregas al arreglo.

Para mostrar la contraseña y el nombre de usuario a la ves, puedes utilizar uno o dos jtextfield.

Te dejo un ejemplo en codigo

```
public class Main implements ActionListener {

    int i = 0;
    JFrame vtn = new JFrame("Prueba boton");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton btn = new JButton("Mostrar");
    JTextField contrasena = new JTextField();
    JTextField usuario = new JTextField();
    Persona[] personas = {new Persona("pedro", 123), new Persona("Esperanza", 456)};

    public Main() {

        vtn.setSize(500, 500);
        vtn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container c = vtn.getContentPane();

        p.setBackground(Color.red);
        
        usuario.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        p.add(usuario);
        contrasena.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        p.add(contrasena);
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        p.add(btn);
        c.add(p);

        vtn.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btn) {
            usuario.setText(personas[i].getNombre());
            contrasena.setText(Integer.toString(personas[i].getContrasena()));
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```